# Clear secondary selection without using mouse

Tags: key-bindings, mouse

Occasionally, without meaning to I somehow mash keys or mouse so that I get a secondary selection.  I never use the secondary selection so I would always like to get rid of it.

How can I clear the secondary selection without using the mouse?

The default bindings for setting the secondary selection are intercepted by my window manager, so do not work in emacs.  I don't really want to rebind these commands to other mouse events either: I use my mouse just for a few things, they work fine and I don't want to change them.  I can't simply run commands like mouse-start-secondary: when I try that, emacs lets me know they have to be bound to an event.

Comment: Does this work: `(delete-overlay secondary-mouse-overlay)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to clear the secondary selection by evaluating:

```
(delete-overlay mouse-secondary-overlay)
```

If you never want to get the secondary selection I believe you can just unbind the default mouse events:

```
(global-unset-key [M-mouse-1])
(global-unset-key [M-drag-mouse-1])
(global-unset-key [M-down-mouse-1])
(global-unset-key [M-mouse-3])
(global-unset-key [M-mouse-2])
```

Comment: I get: Symbols's value as variable is void: secondary-mouse-overlay

Comment: Sorry - I got the name wrong. Fixing it now.

Comment: I'm unable to test this and mark it as accepted answer since I don't know how to get a secondary selection!  When I mark something with secondary selection it's always by accident, so I have no idea how I do it.  Gnome shell seems to intercept all mouse combinations I try... (though I'm not sure what M-down-mouse-1 means)

Comment: I can hold down Alt and the left mouse button to select text with the secondary selection, but no idea about the Gnome interaction.

Comment: Another way you might be getting the secondary selection is with Alt + right-mouse click. That will set the secondary selection from point to wherever you clicked. There are also bindings for Alt + double- or triple-clicking the various buttons. I suspect your window manager steals some but not all of those bindings.

Comment: Last comment: there is a comment here http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection that starting the mouse action and then hitting Alt might bypass the window manager.

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions in these comments and still can't get a secondary selection (except by accident I'm sure) :-(

Answer (score 4):

You say that you never want to use the secondary selection. In that case, just bind the keys that are bound to secondary-selection commands by default to commands that you find more useful. Or unbind them, by binding them to `nil`.  These are those keys:

- **`M-mouse-1`** (`mouse-start-secondary`, by default)
- **`M-drag-mouse-1`** (`mouse-set-secondary`, by default)
- **`M-down-mouse-1`** (`mouse-drag-secondary`, by default)
- **`M-mouse-2`** (`mouse-yank-secondary`, by default)
- **`M-mouse-3`** (`mouse-secondary-save-then-kill`, by default)

For example:

```el
(global-set-key [M-mouse-1] 'a-handy-mouse-command)
```

On the other hand, if the problem is that your window manager steals those keys, then consider binding different keys to those commands. For instance, add modifier `Control` to each of the default keys: `C-M-mouse-1` etc.

```el
(global-set-key [C-M-mouse-1] 'mouse-start-secondary)
```

And if the problem is that you don't want to use the *mouse* for manipulating the secondary selection, then you can use the *keyboard* instead. Library [**`second-sel.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection#secondary-sel.el) can help with this and other ways to use the secondary selection.

For example, you can get rid of the secondary selection interactively anytime this way, if you bind `secondary-dwim` to `C-M-y` (for example):

1. `C-SPC` - to create an empty active region.
2. `C-1 C-M-y` - to move the secondary selection to the region (which is empty).

This is the doc string of command `secondary-dwim`, which `second-sel.el` binds by default to `C-M-y`:

```
C-M-y runs the command secondary-dwim, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `second-sel.el'.

It is bound to C-M-y, menu-bar edit secondary-dwim.

(secondary-dwim ARG)

Do-What-I-Mean with the secondary selection.
Prefix arg:

 None: Yank secondary.
 Zero: Select secondary as region.
 > 0:  Move secondary to region.
 < 0:  Swap region and secondary.

Details:

No prefix arg: Yank the secondary selection at point.  Move point to
the end of the inserted text.  Leave mark where it was.

Zero arg: Select the secondary selection and pop to its buffer.

Non-zero arg: Move the secondary selection to this buffer's region.

Negative arg: Also go to where the secondary selection was and select
it as the region.  That is, swap the region and the secondary
selection.
```